# How to restrict access on changing task status in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

My manager would like to use the Azure DevOps board feature to keep track of her employee's tasks but asked if there is a way so that only she can move or closeout task items. It's a process control issue. Can changing the status (TODO, DOING, DONE) of a task item in Azure DevOps be locked down to a certain role or user account?

Comment: I found this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops. I guess I need to maybe set some of these settings or create a custom role maybe

Comment: Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

From your own comment below your question, it seems that [Set permissions and access for work tracking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops) is a possible answer. Here is a partial quote of it:

> You grant or restrict access to various work tracking features by granting users or groups specific permissions for an object, project, or collection. Or, when you assign a user as a team administrator, they have permissions to manage all assets for the specific team. Add users to the Contributors group to provide access to most features as listed in Permissions and access for work tracking.